# Sql is required error Spring StoredProcedure

Tags: spring, stored-procedures

I am getting property "sql" is required error when i execute below code. can someone help me? i dont know how do i inject Datasource in TestDAO calss so that it works properly.

```
public class TestDAO extends BaseStoredProcedure
{

    final protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

     private static final String SPROC_NAME = "dbo.SP1";


     @Autowired
     private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;




    public java.util.ArrayList<IssuerProductResponse> validIssuersProducts(java.util.ArrayList<IssuerProductRequest> issuersProducts)
    {
        //PARAM MAP set here

        //compile SP
        HIOSBaseStoredProcedure hiosBaseSP = new HIOSBaseStoredProcedure(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource(),SPROC_NAME,inMap,null,null,null);

        //now set parameters

        Map<String, Object> result = super.execute(parameters);
        System.out.println(result);

        return liReponse;
    }


}
```

BaseStoreProcedure class

```
public class BaseStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {


    public BaseStoredProcedure() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param ds
     * @param spname
     * @param map
     * @param sqlOutKey
     * @param returnType
     * @param rowmapper
     */
    public BaseStoredProcedure (DataSource ds, String spname,
            Map<String, Integer> map, String sqlOutKey, Integer returnType,
            RowMapper rowmapper) {
        super();
        setDataSource(ds);

        /* resultset has to be declared first over other declare parameters */
        if (rowmapper != null) {
            declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet(sqlOutKey, rowmapper));
        }

        if (map != null) {
            Iterator itr = map.keySet().iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) itr.next();
                Integer value = (Integer) map.get(key);
                declareParameter(new SqlParameter(key, value.intValue()));
            }
        }

        /*
         * sql out paramter has to be declared based on the order in stored
         * procedures, In all our stored procedures we have it after input
         * parameters
         */
        if (returnType != null) {
            declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(sqlOutKey, returnType
                    .intValue()));
        }

        setSql(spname);
        compile();
    }
}
```

Spring configuration

```
 <bean id="dao" class="test.dao.TestDAO">               <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>     </bean> 
            <bean id="baseSP" class="test.dao.BaseStoredProcedure">         </bean>
         <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
     </bean>
         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"      destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;databaseName=DB;" />       <property name="username" value="username" />       <property name="password" value="password" />               <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />        <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>        <property name="maxActive" value="20"/>     </bean>
```